# javascript: 'return' is ignored and keeps looping

Tags: javascript

```
function checkMagazine(magazine, note) {
    var map = new Map();
    var noteAr = note.split(" ");
    var magazineAr = magazine.split(" ")

    noteAr.forEach((note) => {
        if (map.has(note)) {
            map.set(note, map.get(note) + 1)
        } else {
            map.set(note)
        }
    });

    magazineAr.forEach((word) => {
        if (!map.has(word)) {
            return "No"
        }
    });

    return "Yes"
}
```

I'm checking to see if each word of a note is contained in the magazine by first hashing the values of the note and checking them in magazineAr.  If the note word does not exist in the hash, then I am `return "NO`ing.   However, I keep getting a return "YES" in console.
I've watched it in debugger mode and I see it enter the statement where it hits 'return No' but then it just keeps on going with the forEach loop.  I've even tried `return false` but same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `forEach` callback ignores the value that's returned - no matter what it is, every item in the array will be called with the `forEach`. For what you're trying to do, you should probably use `every` instead, which checks whether all items in the array fulfill the condition:

```
const hasEveryWord = magazineAr.every(word => map.has(word));
return hasEveryWord
  ? "Yes"
  : "No";
```